# Optimizing query with many-to-many relationship on big data set

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, sqlite

I have a database (SQLite) constructed with similar DDL:

```
                                    CREATE TABLE [Player] (
                                        [PlayerID] INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
                                        [Name] TEXT  UNIQUE NULL
                                        );
                                    CREATE TABLE [Position] (
                                        [PlayerID] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
                                        [SingleHandID] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
                                        [Position] INTEGER  NULL,
                                        PRIMARY KEY ([PlayerID],[SingleHandID])
                                        );
                                    CREATE TABLE [SingleHand] (
                                        [SingleHandID] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                        [Stake] FLOAT  NULL,
                                        [Date] DATE  NULL,
                                        DataSetID INTEGER NULL
                                        [IsPreflopAllIn] BOOLEAN  NULL
                                        );

                                    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [NameIndex] ON [Player](
                                        [Name]  ASC

                                    CREATE INDEX [DataSetIndex] ON [SingleHand](
                                    [DataSetID]  ASC
                                    );
```

It is mapped to Entity Framework model. I am working on large data sets up to 10 million records each.

My problem is, that I need to find all Hands where a specific Player is sting on any given Postion (plus some other filters, like date range).

While I can scan the database very quickly, to find data from a single table, for example:

```
//[playerIDs and selectedPos are cashed in memory]

context.Positions.Where(p => playerIDs.Contains(p.PlayerID) && selectedPos.Contains(p.Position)).Select(p => p.SingleHandID).Take(maxHands ?? 1);
```

When I need to do any join between tables, it starts to run very slowly, for example:

```
//accesing both Position and SingleHand table
context.Positions.Where(p => playerIDs.Contains(p.PlayerID) && selectedPos.Contains(p.Position) && p.SingleHand.DataSetID == dataSetNumber).Select(p => p.SingleHandID).Take(maxHands ?? 1);
```

What clever trick, comining queries, and code (ex, with local caching) can I pull, to make this run most efficent? I am using System.Data.SQLite provider.

Maybe I should add redundant DataSetID to Position table, then I can do my main query only on the Position table? Later, when I will have the IDs of all the matching hands, it should be quicker to add additional conditions (like date checking)

Comment: There are too many variables that affect the performance of the query you suggest over 10m records. Table row size, SQL indexes and a bunch of settings. For a rough first shot I'd suggest creating a view, optimize that separately in your DB server then use EF to query that

Comment: `NameIndex` is superfluous because that column already has a `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: To check how well the query is optimized, translate it into SQL and look at the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new index:

```
CREATE INDEX [DataSetIndex2] ON [SingleHand](
    [SingleHandID] ASC,
    [DataSetID]  ASC
);
```

That should help a lot.

You can also try something like this:

```
context.Positions
  .Where(p => playerIDs.Contains(p.PlayerID) && SelectedPos.Contains(p.Position))
  .Select(p => p.SingleHandID)
.Intersect(context.SingleHand
   .Where(s=>s.DataSetId==dataSetNumber)
   .Select(s=>s.SingleHandID))
.Take(maxHands ?? 1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) I need to do some more tests, but it seems, that with that index the performance is acceptable (using the code I posted, trying your Intersect seemed to give wore results in this case).

I have one additional issue - when I add ".OrderBy(p => p.SingleHandID)" to the query, so I can use use paging (to give user some feedback about progress, when he is waiting for this to execute) it slows down terribly - probably I am not using any indexes.

Would it be a good idea to add following index?

INDEX [HandIdIndex] ON [Position]( [SingleHandID] ASC )

Comment: Possibly.  Or you can change your compound primary key to list SingleHandID as the first key.  The performance gain won't be as drastic because you still need to look up the record to filter it, but it might help some.